# Does Wasteland 2 physical DVD includes Steam copy?

Tags: steam, wasteland-2

I would like to have a box copy of Wasteland 2 for aesthetical reasons, but actually I prefer pure Steam in usage. So can I play Wasteland 2 with just a Steam with no disc, after initial installation?

Comment: Please move your p.s. to an answer. It should NOT be in the question. There is nothing wrong with a second answer that adds to the first one.

Comment: @NoneOfYourBusiness agreed, moved to separate answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they do. The game is published by Deep Silver / Koch Media from Germany and all of their recent games are Steamworks. Watch out for the publisher when buying in Russia or Asia though. Could be a different one.

Developer confirming this:

http://steamcommunity.com/app/240760/discussions/0/613936673505002461/#c613936673505223836

[image]

Also, the disc apparently does not include the game, but only the Steam Client:

[image]

Comment: `activiation`, seems like the developer didn t had his coffee : )

Answer (score 0):

To add up to accepted answer. The publisher in ex-USSR is "Бука", but seems like their role is purely nominal, and except for box redesign:

[image: Wasteland 2 CIS DVD box]

all statements in answer are fully applicable to this version too.